# Addition in Button Event C#

Tags: c#

```
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           int a,sum=0;
            a = 10;

            sum = sum + a; 
         MessageBox.Show( sum + "Sum Result");

    }
```

Every time I click on the button I get the answer 10. I want to store result. Suppose I click 5 times then there should be 50.The above code for better understanding should give you some idea of what I'm going for.

Other option if possible I get this result outside of the button event by some method. I am new in C# so feeling lot of problem.

Comment: You aren't summing `a` and `b`. What are their purpose?

Comment: That's because every time you call the method, you re-initialize `sum`. Just declare it outside of the method and in your method, just do `sum += 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tnw tried to tell you - move `sum` outside the function like this:

```
private sum = 0;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     sum = sum + 10; 
     MessageBox.Show( sum + "Sum Result");
}
```

This should work

### explanation

The problem you face is that every variable declared inside a function will get initialized every time you call this function and is discarded when you exit the function.

With the variable beeing outside you made it a field of your class and it will be kept in memory as long as the instance you are using (for example the instance of your form) will be.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `sum=0;` gets re-initialized every time you call the function. Try setting it as a global variable inside the Class and then call it.

This way, when ever the function will be called, the value of `sum` won't get back to 0, but will increment from where it was left.

```
// somewhere above 
int sum = 0;

// then the function
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   sum = sum + 10; 
   MessageBox.Show(sum + " = Sum Result");
}
```

..since you're not using `a` or `b`. I have removed them. However, if you're using them inside the function (in a code which you haven't posted) please add them back.

Each time you called the function, you created new variable called `sum` and if gets deleted at the end of the function. So, each time you pressed the button, sum had a value of *0* in it as initially. Adding 10 to it, would always return 10.

Global variables are declared inside the class itself. Every variable inside the function (such as this one) would be recreated each time you call the function and will have the value you're providing it with. So it is a better approach to write the variables globally, whose value is required next time.